# Is there any existing implementation or logic for Hilbert curve mapping for floating point co-ordinates?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, dimensionality-reduction, hilbert-curve

I am working on implementing a Hilbert curve mapping that uses co-ordinates with floating points. I have come across several Hilbert curve implementations at Github and looks like all of them consider integer co-ordinates only. Though I am working on the logic to process the fractional parts and integer parts separately, would appreciate any leads or pointers that could help me in my implementation.

Comment: the hilbert curve is a discrete algorithm so it inherently uses integers ... simply adapt its output into float as needed

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve exactly, but if you need to order arbitrary points along the Hilbert curve, you might want to consider Hilbert Sort:  https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Spatial_sorting/index.html